# Запись в список без повторений

Tags: python, python-3.x

С сайта отлавливаю переменную **name_elem_site**. Не могу правильно сделать проверку **если текущее слово не равно последней записи в список, то добавляем слово**.
Т.е. с сайта приходит

> Слово1, Слово3, Слово1, Слово2, СловоN, ...

У меня получается в логе, сколько весело слово от мс до сек, столько раз и запишет:

> Слово1, Слово1, Слово1, Слово2, Слово2, Слово2,....

И из-за этого я не могу потом подсчитать сколько раз выводилось слово. Т.к. Слово1 показалось только 1 раз на 20 сек, к примеру, так у меня в логах и написано, что 20 значений внесено.

```
name_elem_site = text_element_by_class_name(driver, "texttexttext")
currentList = []
currentWord = currentList.append(str(name_elem_site))

if name_elem_site:
    for word in currentList:
        if word == currentWord:
            continue
        currentWord = word
        currentList.append(word)
        log.write("%s\n" % word)
        log.flush()
```

Comment: У вас в 3 строчке переменной currentWorld всегда присваивается None, потому что append ничего не возвращает.

Comment: и как исправить для особо отдаренных?

Comment: currentList.append(str(name_elem_site)) и на новой строке currentWord = currentList[-1] или currentWord = str(name_elem_site)

Comment: тесно связанные вопросы: [Запись переменной(?) в файл и проверка на ввод одинаковых данных подряд с предыдущим значением](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606029/23044) и 
[Исключить ввод одинаковых подряд данных](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606201/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверка последнего элемента

```
if currentList[-1] != word
   currentList.append(word)
```

Проверка на вхождение в список вообще

```
if word not in currentList:
   currentList.append(word)
```