# Исключить ввод одинаковых подряд данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Имеется вот такой код.

```
name_elem_site = text_element_by_class_name(driver, "texttexttext")
currentList = []
currentWord = currentList.append(str(name_elem_site))

if name_elem_site:
    for word in currentList:
        if word == currentWord:
            continue
        currentWord = word
        currentList.append(word)
        log.write("%s\n" % word)
        log.flush()
```

Задача: получать данные по слову и записывать в список, без записи подряд идущих данных.
Т.е. должно быть так

> Слово1, Слово2, Слово1, Слово3, Слово2, Слово3, Слово2, .., СловоN

А у меня получается

> Слово1, Слово1, Слово1, Слово2, Слово2, Слово2, Слово3, .., СловоN

Пытался добавить `if currentList[-1] != word`

Но результат тот же...

```
name_elem_site = text_element_by_class_name(driver, "texttexttext")
currentList = []
currentWord = currentList.append(str(name_elem_site))

if name_elem_site:
    for word in currentList:
        if word == currentWord:
            continue
        currentWord = word
        if currentList[-1] != word: # последний элемент не равен текущему
           currentList.append(word)
        log.write("%s\n" % word)
        log.flush()
```

Как поступить? Новичок, не могу догадаться.

Comment: В вопросе используйте минимально рабочий пример кода. Догадаться что возвращает ваш метод text_element_by_class_name() не может никто, кроме вас.

Comment: @Alexey, я написал, например, вместо name_elem_site = Слово1. Через какое-то время Слово2 и так далее, могут быть повторы, главное в запись отрубить подряд идущие одинаковые слова.

Comment: Запоминайте последнее слово и проверяйте что новое слово != последнее.

Comment: Если name_elem_site = 'Слово1', то весь остальной код становится бессмысленным, поскольку currentList в этом случае всегда состоит из 1 элемента. Если это два разных фрагмента кода из разных частей программы - стоит как-то это отметить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из предположения, что вы каким-то образом получаете список, могу предложить использовать что-то такое:

```
# Допустим у вас как-то получился вот такой список
initial_words_list = ['Слово1', 'Слово2', 'Слово1', 'Слово3', 'Слово3', 'Слово1', 'Слово1', 'Слово1', 'Слово1',
                      'Слово3', 'Слово2', 'Слово2', 'Слово2', 'Слово1', 'Слово1', 'Слово2', 'Слово3', 'Слово3',
                      'Слово3', 'Слово2', 'Слово2', 'Слово2', 'Слово2', 'Слово1', 'Слово1', 'Слово1', 'Слово2']
result_list = []  # создадим пустой список, в который будем складывать неповторяющиеся слова
previous_word = ''  # создаем пустую текстовую переменную, в которую будем записывать предыдущее слово
for word in initial_words_list:
    if word != previous_word:  # если текущее слово не равно предыдущему
        result_list.append(word)  # записываем его в список-результат
    previous_word = word

print(result_list)  # ['Слово1', 'Слово2', 'Слово1', 'Слово3', 'Слово1', 'Слово3', 'Слово2', 'Слово1', 'Слово2', 'Слово3', 'Слово2', 'Слово1', 'Слово2']
```

Comment: возможно у меня в самом начале проблема с моим списком. Т.к. я не могу даже знать какие там слова будут. Т.е. генерация на ходу с сайта. Поэтому изначально, якобы, список пустой. После появления я вношу туда данные.
Получается список вообще не нужен в этой части?
Т.е. проще получить СловоN и записать в файл значение, затем открыть файл и если последняя строка = полученному новому значению, то пропустить и ждать след слова.
Так что ли?

Comment: @J.Doe, приведите пожалуйста код, генерирующий список. В приведенном вами коде список сначала обнуляется, а потом в него добавляется один элемент.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте функцию groupby из стандартной библиотеки itertools

```
from itertools import groupby

l = ['Слово1', 'Слово1', 'Слово2', 'Слово2', 'Слово3', 'Слово4', 'Слово4']

new_l = [word for word, group in groupby(l)]

print(new_l)

# Напечатает: ['Слово1', 'Слово2', 'Слово3', 'Слово4']
```

PS: Изучайте стандартные библиотеки. Их не просто так добавили в сам язык.

Comment: наверное, я не правильно поставил условие. Повторы могут быть, но не подряд.
# Напечатает: ['Слово1', 'Слово2', 'Слово1', 'Слово2', 'Слово3']
Так нужно.
# Так нельзя : ['Слово1', 'Слово1', 'Слово2', 'Слово2', 'Слово1']

Comment: Удаление дубликатов через groupby можно заменить множеством: `print(set(l))`

Comment: @gil9red, new_l = set(l)
тоже убирает вообще повторы
`l = ['Слово1', 'Слово2', 'Слово2', 'Слово1', 'Слово2', 'Слово3', 'Слово1']`
возвращает только 
`{'Слово3', 'Слово2', 'Слово1'}`
а мне надо 
` {'Слово1', 'Слово2', 'Слово1', 'Слово2', 'Слово3', 'Слово1'}`

Comment: @J.Doe а я это и сказал Александр'у :)
А то, как вас решить этот вопрос написал в комментарии к вопросу

Comment: groupby как раз таки "схлопывает" не все повторы, а только идущие подряд. Попробуйте сами на ваших данных.

Comment: @Александр в рецептах в документации itertools это называется [`unique_justseen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes): `map(itemgetter(0), groupby(L))`

Comment: @gil9red нельзя groupby на set заменять: сравните что делают unique_justseen() и unique_everseen() рецепты в itertools (автор первое хочет).