# Запись в файл с проверкой последней строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть переменная `name_elem_site`, значение которой необходимо записать в файл. Значение получаем из стороннего источника.

Есть файл, изначально пустой.

Нужно дописать значение переменной `name_elem_site` в этот файл на новой строке, но только в случае, если значение переменной не совпадает с последней строкой этого файла.

Например, если последовательно приходят строки:

```
Текст 
Текст 
Текст 
Текст2 
Текст 
Текст3 
Текст2 
Текст
```

То в файл запишется только

```
Текст  
Текст2 
Текст 
Текст3 
Текст2 
Текст
```

т.к. были три подряд идущие одинаковые значения, а такое запрещено.

Comment: Если программа работает постоянно, сохраняем предыдущее значение и перед записью сравниваем с новым. Если записывает только одну строку за всю свою работу, то читаем файл, выбираем последнюю строку и сравниваем. В каком месте у Вас возникает проблема?

Comment: @kff в проверке на последнею строку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Считывание последней строки из файла.

---

***Первый вариант.*** Самый простой. Но файл должен целиком помещаться в память. В случае пустого файла работает некорректно.

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
    last_line = file.readlines()[-1].strip()
```

(Считываем все строки файла в список, берём последнюю, убираем символ новой строки, если он есть.)

---

***Второй вариант.*** Чуть сложнее. Но не требует памяти для хранения файла целиком. В случае пустого файла также работает некорректно.

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
    for last_line in file:
        pass
    last_line = last_line.strip()
```

(Читаем файл построчно. В переменной сохранится последняя прочитанная строка. Затем опять-таки удаляем символ новой строки, если таковой имеется.)

---

***Третий вариант.*** Аналогичен первому, но корректно работает и в случае пустого файла. В этом случае `last_line` будет содержать значение `None`.

```
last_line = None
with open('test.txt') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    if lines:
        last_line = lines[-1].strip()
```

---

***Четвёртый вариант.*** Аналогичен второму, но корректно работает и в случае пустого файла. В этом случае `last_line` будет содержать значение `None`.

```
last_line = None
with open('test.txt') as file:
    for last_line in file:
        pass
    if last_line:
        last_line = last_line.strip()
```

Comment: оу, спасибо! Пойду пробовать на деле + проверку на подряд одинаковые данные проверю заодно.

Comment: Если файл в памяти не помещается, лучше с конца `'\n'` поискать, *чтобы последнюю строчку найти*, вместо того чтобы целиком проходить по файлу (`deque(file, maxlen=1)`). К примеру если mmap файл как `s`: `i = s.rfind(b'\n', 0, -1); last_line = (s[i+1:] if i != -1 else s).decode()`. Можно ещё `file.seek()` использовать, но [код сложнее](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7167008/4279)

Answer (score 0):

```
def elem_write(name_elem_site: str, file='test.txt', last_line=''):
    with open(file) as fr, open(file, 'a') as fa:
        for last_line in fr:pass
        if not last_line.rstrip() == name_elem_site:
            print(name_elem_site, file=fa)
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы записать в файл строки так чтобы смежные значения не повторялись, можно использовать [`itertools.groupby()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/615458/23044):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from itertools import groupby

lines = ['Текст','Текст','Текст', 'Текст2', 'Текст', 'Текст3', 'Текст2', 'Текст']
with open('uniq_just_seen.txt', 'w') as file: # start  with empty file
    file.writelines(line + '\n' for line, _ in groupby(lines))
```

#### Результат в `uniq_just_seen.txt` файле

```
Текст
Текст2
Текст
Текст3
Текст2
Текст
```

Вместо списка `lines` можно использовать произвольную коллекцию, к примеру, строки, прочитанные со стандартного ввода: `lines = map(str.strip, sys.stdin)` или посчитанные каким-либо алгоритмом:

```
import random

def generate_lines(choices):
    while random.random() < 0.9: # 10% to exit
        yield random.choice(choices)

lines = generate_lines(['Текст', 'Текст2', 'Текст3'])
```